# Should I use mockups instead of photos to display my products on the web?

Tags: website-design, critique

I have a website for "[regalos frikis](https://frikinow.com)", the problem is that I do not have product photos, so I have to use mockups.

My question is, are the mockups too unrealistic? Should you avoid using them on the web?

Comment: This is a common practice - for example most t-shirt selling sites use just one photo of a model with their t-shirt on, and they just change it's color and/or content. Making hundreds or even thousands (even more in a long run) photos of objects for sale is tedious to say the least - especially when your business is small, and you don't have resources to spend on photo shoots. Oh, and mockups on your site look fine. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments against mockups: they look unrealistic.

But actually,  badly or too much shoped pictures does too (you know those t-shirts photos where t-shirt is #000000 black everywhere).

So argument for using mockups:

1. Save time (you don't need to organize photoshoots and have prepared items)
2. Save money (you don't have to pay for model, photographer, any equipment, and preparing photos)
3. Whole process can be automated (which of course relate to points 1 and 2) but give your photos an unified looks. Think of it as a site identity. What will attract the customer is the design on the item not the fact that the product is slightly crooked, darker, framed differently.

If you are afraid of "unrealisticness" just use a source file the best real photo. The warping on the cup? Incorporate it into your mockup file. 
Even car photos are mocked up. From the fake "on the road" photos to session photos.